# Get source of webpage accessible after login in android app

Tags: android

I need to get HTML source of page that is accessible after login. In login form it also has field for anti CSRF token. 
I really can't find out how to do that, can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

```
  HttpClient myclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
  HttpGet myrequest = new HttpGet(url);
  HttpResponse myresponse = client.execute(request);

  String htmlsource = "";
  InputStream in = myresponse.getEntity().getContent();
   BufferedReader myreader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
  StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
   String line = null;
    while((line = myreader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        string.append(line);
    }
 in.close();
  htmlsource = string.toString();
```

you can get the source code of a given url using this hop eit will be help to you

Comment: This will get source code of simple page, but how to login?
Iˇve already done that in C#, it was something like GET to page for retrieve login page, save cookies and then send POST request with attached cookie container from previous req. but how to do that on android?